# Select a TreeNode in TreeView in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TreeView Control in my aspx page.

Each TreeNode has a Text & Value property in that.

for e.g.

```
TreeView Tr_View = new TreeView();
                    TreeNode TrNode=new TreeNode("ABC","1");
                    Tr_View.Nodes.Add(TrNode);
                    TrNode = new TreeNode("DEF", "5");
                    Tr_View.Nodes.Add(TrNode);
                    TrNode = new TreeNode("GHI", "9");
                    Tr_View.Nodes.Add(TrNode);
                    TrNode = new TreeNode("JKL", "11");
                    Tr_View.Nodes.Add(TrNode);
```

The Problem is that I want to select 3rd node on the basis of its value "9"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to find node with value "9" and select it:

```
var node = Tr_View.FindNode("9");
node.Select();
```

Note that "9" here is a path to node. So if you will have nodes at non-root
level, you will need to specify full path, like "root.child.9".

If you don't have a full path, probably the best way to find a node based on node value 
would be to traverse all tree nodes:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetAllNodes()
{
  Stack<TreeNode> roots = new Stack<TreeNode>(Tr_View.Nodes);
  while(roots.Count > 0)
  {
    var node = roots.Pop();
    foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
      roots.Push(child);

    yield return node;
  }
}
...
var allNodesWithValue9 = GetAllNodes().Where(n => n.Value == "9");
```

Comment: .SelectedNode is a READ ONLY property. Your first solution doesn't work